# Why won't the latest version of Stripe gradle allow .setName?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe payments and the latest version for gradle stated to be `com.stripe:stripe-android:9.2.0`. Yet I am not able to use the `.setName` function to add to the card data. Why is this the case? I had to revert to an older `9.1.1` version to be able to accomplish this.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Card cardToSave = mCardInputWidget.getCard();
                Card.Builder builder = new Card.Builder(cardToSave.getName()); // pass the arguments here
                builder.setName(cardHolderName);
                Card newCard = builder.build();

                Stripe stripe = new Stripe(paymentContext, publishableApiKey );
                stripe.createToken(newCard, publishableApiKey, new TokenCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Token result) {
                        // Create plan
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });
```

Comment: have you try to contact the stripe support team? what they have told

Comment: No response. It's been a couple of hours already.

Comment: The Stripe team is basically US based and it is night time currently. So you will have to wait till the evening for the response

Comment: Yeah I figured, which is why I posted here. I can't possibly be the only one who has experienced this.

Comment: have you tried to go through the documentation or the method names available?

Comment: i am currently using `implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.7.0'` and it is not showing anyupdate to the implementation you are using

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I did. I updated my question with the code.

Comment: You also need to set cardNumber, expiryMonth, expiryDate, CVV etc in the builder you got from **cardToSave** variable.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid that, which is why I used the given form; but fine. I will try that as well. But I haven't even compiled the code, let alone request a token and the syntax is giving me problems.

Comment: i have basically developed the same functionality in kotlin language so i have to convert it to java. I hope you understood what is required in the Card.Builder constructor. :)

Comment: If it lead you to right direction don't forget to accept the answer so it could help other SO users here

Comment: I haven't got it completely but I am getting it slowly :) Do I need to create a POJO since I am getting and setting the name, date, cvv etc.?

Comment: Ah, you already created that in your answer. I just have to add the actual variables in there.

Comment: yes.. Just give it a try to my edited answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out when you use constructor it receives name as argument.
On the latest library `com.stripe:stripe-android:9.2.0` it changes the way it was before

```
private Card(@NonNull Builder builder) {
    this.number = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(normalizeCardNumber(builder.number));
    this.expMonth = builder.expMonth;
    this.expYear = builder.expYear;
    this.cvc = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.cvc);
    this.name = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.name);
    this.addressLine1 = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressLine1);
    this.addressLine1Check = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressLine1Check);
    this.addressLine2 = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressLine2);
    this.addressCity = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressCity);
    this.addressState = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressState);
    this.addressZip = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressZip);
    this.addressZipCheck = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressZipCheck);
    this.addressCountry = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.addressCountry);
    this.last4 = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.last4) == null
            ? calculateLast4(number, builder.last4)
            : builder.last4;
    this.brand = asCardBrand(builder.brand) == null
            ? calculateBrand(builder.brand)
            : builder.brand;
    this.fingerprint = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.fingerprint);
    this.funding = asFundingType(builder.funding);
    this.country = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.country);
    this.currency = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.currency);
    this.customerId = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.customer);
    this.cvcCheck = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.cvcCheck);
    this.id = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.id);
    this.tokenizationMethod = StripeTextUtils.nullIfBlank(builder.tokenizationMethod);
    this.metadata = builder.metadata;
}
```

or you can use Builder method to it also has `.name(@Nullable String name)` method which you can use.

**Recommended way**
is to use `Card.Builder()` and pass the arguments in the builder itself. Let me know if you need any help

**EDIT**

currently you can workaround the below condition like this:

```
Card cardToSave = mCardInputWidget.getCard();
Card.Builder builder = new Card.Builder( String number, Integer expMonth, Integer expYear, String cvc); // pass the arguments here
builder.setName("");
Card newCard = builder.build();
newCard.setName(cardHolderName);
// use this **newCard** for payment
```

Comment: Yes, I do need help since I am integrating a payment gateway for the first time. I don't quite understand how I would use the builder function to just add the cardholder name to the card.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but wouldn't you need a builder when you are building your custom form? I am using the one provided by Stripe and just adding the cardholder name. That's it.

Comment: i was using custom in my app

Comment: I updated your code as little as possible and am now getting 2 errors: 1) The "cardToSave.getName() cannot be resolved. The argument does not match.

Comment: The 2nd error involves the setName function. It cannot be resolved.

Comment: Yes in the cardBuilder constructor it accepts **String number, Integer expMonth, Integer expYear, String cvc**

Comment: @BVB09 i have updated my answer with arguments you need to pass